# How to save dropdown slection by a user in the DB

Tags: database, users, dropdown

I'm having a blog system about cars. I have two main types of articles/posts there. One type is depends on the car manufacturer.

1/Parent category-Car Manufacturer/ Sub categories- Toyota,Honda, TATA...etc

Every time when a new user register, he/she has to select his/her car from a DROPDOWN.

How can I save that(user selected car brand) in my DB according to the user? Do I need to modify my DB by adding tables? or what is the best way to save that in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can update user meta either through custom code or using a plugin. Advanced custom fields will solve your issue.
Check out the reference links for more info :

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-use-acf-to-add-user-profile-meta/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/